# Add field ModelBuilder ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm making my first ModelBuilder and my issue is about trying to get my firstly made "dissolve.shp" into an ADD JOIN like an input layer name not like a join table. (as you can see in the picture there is only that option)
[image]
Where my normal way is: Dissolve -> Add Join -> Export data -> Save like a new .shp... I don't know how to do this process by ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add join wants a feature layer as input, you are trying with the feature class output from dissolve. With dissolve.shp as input use Make Feature Layer to create a feature layer.

Then connect the join table and Copy Features to save.

[image]

If it is only one field you want to join/add you can also use Join Field instead of Make Feature Layer - Add Join - Copy Features, but I usually dont, it can be slow.